# Using Go for ClassificationBox

Tags: docker, powershell, go, docker-compose

So I've been trying to build a simple fake news detector using MachineBox's ClassificationBox. I referenced [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-i-trained-an-ai-to-detect-satire-in-under-an-hour-2b8b300ea805#--respond) and followed the steps. I've been using PowerShell to run the code stated in that article. However, I got an error message and I don't quite know what to do. Currently, the "main.go" file is in my Go folder in my C drive, and the "fakenews" folder is in my "testdata" folder located in the Go folder.

The error message is as follows:

main.go:17:2: cannot find package "github.com/machinebox/sdk-go/boxutil" in any of:

```
    c:\go\src\github.com\machinebox\sdk-go\boxutil (from $GOROOT)

    C:\Users\gsime\Desktop\go-workspace\src\github.com\machinebox\sdk-go\boxutil (from $GOPATH)
```

main.go:18:2: cannot find package "github.com/machinebox/sdk-go/classificationbox" in any of:

```
    c:\go\src\github.com\machinebox\sdk-go\classificationbox (from $GOROOT)

    C:\Users\gsime\Desktop\go-workspace\src\github.com\machinebox\sdk-go\classificationbox (from $GOPATH)
```

main.go:19:2: cannot find package "github.com/pkg/errors" in any of:

```
    c:\go\src\github.com\pkg\errors (from $GOROOT)

    C:\Users\gsime\Desktop\go-workspace\src\github.com\pkg\errors (from $GOPATH)
```

main.go:20:2: cannot find package "gopkg.in/cheggaaa/pb.v1" in any of:

```
    c:\go\src\gopkg.in\cheggaaa\pb.v1 (from $GOROOT)

    C:\Users\gsime\Desktop\go-workspace\src\gopkg.in\cheggaaa\pb.v1 (from $GOPATH)
```

I could really use some help with this.. Thanks!

Comment: Did you `go get` the package you need before trying to run the code?

Comment: By that do you mean did I have Classification Box running on Docker? I did that.. But I'm not sure if I need to get any other package before running this code.

Comment: No, I mean have you gone and got all the packages your code needs. for example run the command `go get github.com/machinebox/sdk-go/boxutil` (along with all the other dependencies your code needs)

Comment: Basically, the error messages are telling you that you're trying to use a load of external packages which are not on your local machine

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now. Thank you!